# Does any modern Buddhist tradition use a Gregorian holiday schedule?

Tags: traditions, holidays

Have any modern Buddhist organization adopted the Gregorian calendar for celebrating Buddhist holidays?

Last time I tried to find something simple as Vesak or some of the other common Buddhist Holiday's, they are celebrated on a lunar calendar and differ from country to country, ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesak#Dates_of_observance

I'm not affiliated with any particular organized sangha, so I have two challenges-- deciding which holidays to celebrate, and even after that, there isn't a lot of agreement on how to calculate the day.

Comment: Japanese tradition holidays are very different. But for Vesak, you just need the full moon day in May. One of those calendars that shows the moon phases is useful.

Comment: You could try the FPMT Dharma calendar: "http://fpmt.org/media/resources/dharma-dates/" Astrology is rather big in Buddhism, but I don't tend to follow it as I never did previously growing up. It does help, I reckon, to show what the upcoming religious significant dates might be.

Comment: To MatthewMartin, I think your web site (http://brahmanetproject.wakayos.com/) comment system is broken (or I am not clever enough to login to it). It asks me for password after signing in via Facebook but there is nowhere to create or get a password. Thought you should know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look around and I can't see actual Buddhist holidays that follow a Gregorian calendar. They all seem to shift around with lunar cycles. The [Thai national calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_solar_calendar) is a renumbered Gregorian calendar but the [Buddhist festivals within that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Thailand) are lunar

However I practice with the [Triratna Buddhist community](https://thebuddhistcentre.com/text/what-triratna-buddhist-community) in the UK and we have over a number of years celebrated 'Gregorian' festivals. For instance we have a lovely Buddhist ritual on winter solstice and then again on New Years Eve. I'm not sure if this quite answers your question and I appreciate that this isn't traditional or even standard but I think it's interesting that we are repurposing these days as Buddhist festivals just as Christians repurposed pagan festivals for Christmas and Easter.

So perhaps there are no Gregorian festivals (that I know of) right now but 'Western' Buddhist communities will be busily repurposing existing Gregorian festivals just like we are. Just a thought really.

Comment: I concur. I remember a poorly thought out radio article where the journalist checked in with each world religion to see how they celebrate Christmas (as if a religion necessarily entails a major winter holiday). I've seen photos of Buddhists in Hawaii who repurposed Bodhi Day (Dec 8) as a time to put out Buddhist themed light displays on their lawn. Ref http://familydharma.pulelehuadesign.com/bodhi.htm